# Sumar tablas en WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hola gente soy nuevo en WordPress y necesito ayuda. Quiero crear una página en WordPress cuando le hagan click a un checkbox sume  todos los productos de una categoría y los clasifique por mes. Yo en php lo pude hacer mediante ajax php MySQL pero en WordPress no sé cómo empezar. Leí usando hook en fuction, pero los hook se pueden aplicar solo a páginas en concreto. Necesito una orientación

Comment: es en frontend o backend? que estarías sumando? 'productos' es un custom post type propio o de algún plugin ( onda woocommerce ) ? . hay diferentes tipos de hooks : actions ( acciones, hacer algo antes o despues de algo ) y filters ( filtros, modificar algo ) y se pueden aplicar a casi cualquier cosa que lo tenga definido

Comment: Si de woocommerce. A dónde pones los hooks en el archivo fuction. O puedo usar un snippte